# Highcharts: column chart with separate categories

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'd like to show two or more data sets as subsequent columns. For example, I'd like one data set to take up the left half of the column chart and another data set to take up the right half of the chart. I don't want them to share xAxis categories.

I'd like a simple solution that has separate legend series and automatic colors.

The closest thing I could find was the [Grouped Categories plugin](http://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/11/Grouped-Categories) but that doesn't account for multiple, separate data sets.

Comment: I would just make two charts side by side...

Comment: As in two separate charts in the HTML? That's not what I need. I want each of the data to take up half of the chart.

Comment: Yes, so I gathered from your post. Which is what prompted me to post an alternative approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To build a chart like this you can utilize a stacked column chart and add null values to the indexes of the other data set's actual values.

```
    series: [{
        name: 'John',
        data: [null, null, 4, 7]
    }, {
        name: 'Jane',
        data: [2, 3, null, null]
    }]
```

Have a look at this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/andrewscheuermann/6vgvey1f/3/) for an example.